# How can I loop Json with dynamic type in .netcore 1.1?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, json-deserialization

I have passed Json object though Postman. And I have no idea how can I loop this with .NetCore 1.1 Web Service.

Json Object passed by Postman:

```
{
 [
  {"id":"1","name":"Peter"}
  ,
  {"id":"2","name":"Mary"}
 ]
}
```

.net core 1.1 coding:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("all")]
public IActionResult UpdateName([FromBody] dynamic JSON){
  var RootObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JSON);
  foreach (var x in RootObjects){
   // do something here...
  }
}
```

RootObjects:

```
private class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And I get error below:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )\r\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your json is invalid.Change your  json string to:

```
 [
  {"id":"1","name":"Peter"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Mary"}
 ]
```

And change your controller action to:

```
   [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody] List<RootObject> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.name);
        }

        return Json("ok");
    }
```

And also the RootObject class need to Public:

```
     public class RootObject
     {
       public string id { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
     }
```

Use the postman put string in Content-Type:application/json. And i saw the correct result.